# Getting how many days users have logged in during a month (same day counts as 1 log in)

Tags: mysql, query

Let's see if you can help me with a query. I want to know how many times users have logged in during a month.

If I have this data:

| id_log | id_user | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-02-22 15:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-02-23 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 3 | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 3 | 2022-02-24 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 3 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 1 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 9 | 2 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 |

Result:

| year | month | times | number_of_users_logged_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 2 | 1 | 2 (id_user 2 and 3) |
| 2022 | 2 | 2 | 1 (id_user 1) |
| 2022 | 2 | 3 | 1 (id_user 3) |
| 2022 | 3 | 1 | 2 (id_user 1 and 2) |

Notice that user 1 has logged in twice on the 22nd but only counts as one.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: ```COUNT(DISTINCT id_user, DATE(`timestamp`))``` in subquery then aggregate by `(year, month, count)` and count users amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the expected result are not correct because user 1 in 2 month is logged twice not once. 2022-02-22 00:00:00 2022-02-22 15:00:00 counts as one and the second log-in 2022-02-23 00:00:00

Maybe this would help:

```
select t1.Year,month,t1.user as times,group_concat(t1.id_user) as users_logged_in
from ( select month(`timestamp`) as month ,
              count(distinct id_user, 
              date(`timestamp`)) as user ,
              id_user,
              year(`timestamp`) as Year
       from test_tbl
       group by   month(`timestamp`),id_user,year(`timestamp`)
       ) as t1
group by  t1.Year,month  ,times    
order by month asc,times asc;
```

**Results**

| Year | month | times | users_logged_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022 | 3 | 1 | 1,2 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bf296a6002517c9482746aee754ac57)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks